# Error: QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (1, 0) already taken

Tags: qt, qml

[image]I am getting console message for below shown code using GridLayout:

```
Rectangle{
        id: topRect
        color: "transparent"

        border {
            width: 1
            color: "gray"
        }
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width

    Flickable {
            id: flickableArea
            clip: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentHeight: gridContainer.height
            contentWidth: gridContainer.width
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragAndOvershootBounds
            flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

            GridLayout{
                id: gridContainer
                rows: 10
                columns: 3
                width: topRect.width
                columnSpacing: 0
                rowSpacing: 0

                Repeater{
                     model: 10*3
                     Rectangle{
                         width: 415
                         height: 110
                         border.color: "blue"
                         color: "transparent"
                     }
                 }

                Rectangle {
                    id: rect1
                    width: 138
                    height: 110
                    Layout.row: 1
                    Layout.column: 0
                    color: "red"
                }
              Rectangle {
                id: rect2
                width: 138
                height: 110
                Layout.row: 2
                Layout.column: 0
                color: "blue"
            }
            }
}
```

Without repeater i am not getting this kind of console message but with repeater i am getting it. Repeater i need and that is the requirement.

Why i am getting warning message?

```
QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (1, 0) already taken
QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (2, 0) already taken
```

Is there any way to fix it or stop reflecting in console?

Comment: i guess the error message is pretty clear.  what cell/row do you think will get  the 4-th and 7-th item of the `Repeater`? You try to put Rectangles into cells that already taked, thats all. Just put it outside the `GridLayout`, or before the `Repeater`

Comment: If your goal is just to make the warning go away, place the `Repeater` code below `Rectangle`s, but the result is probably not what you actually wanted. What exactly do you want it to draw?

Comment: I want grid like shown in the image and place the rectangles in whatever row i want. Also red rectangle height gets increased on some operation. That is why i want repeater and without repeater i am not getting expected result i.e height is not getting increased properly. With repeater i am getting expected result but the warning message i m getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Repeater creates the 30 items that occupy all the cells but then you try to replace those cells and it makes GridLayout launch that warning. One possible solution is to create the items using Component.createObject to set it as a child of the items that meet the condition based on the row and column.

```
Rectangle{
    id: topRect
    color: "transparent"
    border {
        width: 1
        color: "gray"
    }
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    Component{
        id: rectangleProvider
        Rectangle{
            width: 138
            height: 110
        }
    }
    function createRectangle(row, column, item){
        var color;
        if(row == 1 &&  column == 0){
            color = "red"
        }
        else if(row == 2 &&  column == 0){
            color = "blue"
        }
        if(color !== undefined){
            var it = rectangleProvider.createObject(item, {"color": color})
        }
    }

    Flickable {
        id: flickableArea
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: gridContainer.height
        contentWidth: gridContainer.width
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragAndOvershootBounds
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        GridLayout{
            id: gridContainer
            rows: 10
            columns: 3
            width: topRect.width
            columnSpacing: 0
            rowSpacing: 0

            Repeater{
                model: 10*3
                Rectangle{
                    id: item
                    width: 415
                    height: 110
                    border.color: "blue"
                    color: "transparent"
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        var row = Math.floor(index/gridContainer.columns)
                        var column = index - gridContainer.columns*row
                        topRect.createRectangle(row, column, item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```